# Merging JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am creating a project using JavaScript. I am trying to add values into JavaScript array of objects basis on certain conditions. Everything is working fine and I have achieved the expected output but the only problem is code looks very lengthy.

```js
let f1Response = [{
  "uuid": "1",
  "name": "f1",

}]
    
let f2Response = [{
    "name": "f2",
    "f1uuid": "1",
    "f3uuid":"3"

}]

let f3Response = [{
    "name": "f3",
    "uuid": "3",

}]
    
for(var i=0; i<f2Response.length; i++){
  for(var j=0;j<f3Response.length; j++){
    if(f3Response[j]['uuid'] == f2Response[i]['f3uuid']){
     f2Response[i]['f3Name'] = f3Response[j]['name']
    }
  }
} 
          
for(var ik=0; ik<f2Response.length; ik++){
  for(var jk=0;jk<f1Response.length; jk++){
    if(f1Response[jk]['uuid'] ==f2Response[ik]['f1uuid']){
      f2Response[ik]['f1Name'] = f1Response[jk]['name']
    }
  }
}
console.log(f2Response)
```

output:

Please suggest the better idea to achieve this in shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to do that.

```js
let f1Response = [{
  "uuid": "1",
  "name": "f1",

}]
    
let f2Response = [{
    "name": "f2",
    "f1uuid": "1",
    "f3uuid":"3"

}]

let f3Response = [{
    "name": "f3",
    "uuid": "3",

}]

f2Response = f2Response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   const { f3uuid, f1uuid } = curr;
   
   let f3Index = f3Response.findIndex(item => item.uuid === f3uuid);
   let f1Index = f1Response.findIndex(item => item.uuid === f1uuid);
   
   const {name: f3name} = f3Response[f3Index];
   const {name: f1name} = f1Response[f1Index];
   
   acc.push({...curr, f3name, f1name,});
   return acc;
}, []);
    

console.log(f2Response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `f1Response` and `f3Response` to [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of `[uuid, name]`. Now [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `f2Response` and get the names by their respective uuids:

```js
const createNamesMap = arr => 
  new Map(arr.map(item => [item.uuid, item.name]))
  
const combine = (f1, f2, f3) => {
  const f1Map = createNamesMap(f1) // create a Map of f1 name by uuid
  const f3Map = createNamesMap(f3) // create a Map of f3 name by uuid
  
  return f2.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    f3Name: f3Map.get(item.f3uuid), // get f3 name
    f1Name: f1Map.get(item.f1uuid) // get f1 name
  }))
}

const f1Response = [{"uuid": "1","name": "f1"}]
const f2Response = [{"name": "f2","f1uuid": "1","f3uuid": "3"}]
const f3Response = [{"name": "f3","uuid": "3"}]

const result = combine(f1Response, f2Response, f3Response)

console.log(result)
```